# Crystal Reports dynamic group summary

Tags: dynamic, grouping, crystal-reports-2008

I'm trying to figure out a way to dynamically create a report summary that lists the totals of instances for each account dynamically at the beginning or end of the report.  An account will only show up on the report if that account had any instances in the date/time range established by the Start/End date parameter fields, so every account will not always show, hence the dynamic part of the problem.  There is surprising sparse information on how to do this from what I've found.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Insert, CrossTab...
Select Account as the row and select the value you wish to summarize.

There are many other options if you look into CrossTab features...

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  Thank you greatly!